# Vuetify pagination not updating reactive variable

Tags: vue.js, pagination, vuetify.js, vue-reactivity, v-data-table

I'm following this simple example of vuetify external pagination https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/pagination/#external-pagination . Difference is that my code gets the data from an asynchronous request. Surprisingly it doesn't work.

Possible that I'm doing something wrong, but reactivity examples with composition api are not a lot out there.
Template:

```
 <template>
   <v-container class="w-100">
     <v-card>
       <v-card-title align="left" class="mb-5 mt-3">Users</v-card-title>
       <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="users"
        :items-per-page="pageSize"
        hide-default-footer
        class="elevation-1"
       >
       <template v-slot:bottom>
         <div class="text-center pt-2">
           <v-pagination
             v-model="page"
            :length="pageNumbers"
           ></v-pagination>
        </div>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-card>
 </v-container>
</template>
```

Script short version:

```
const users = ref([])
const pageSize = ref(10)
const page = ref(1)
const totalUserCount = ref(1)
const pageNumbers = computed(() => Math.ceil(totalUserCount.value / pageSize.value))

const loadUsers = async (page) => {
  await HTTPClient.getData('/user-manager/users?page=' + page).then(response => {
    users.value = response.data.result
    pageSize.value = response.data.page_size
    totalUserCount.value = response.data.count
});
```

}

```
await loadUsers(page.value)
```

Now when clicking on the pagination button, my guess is that it should update the page reactive variable, which then should re-render the component (including the loadUser function call). But nothing happens.
I'm quite new with vue, so maybe I shouldn't think in React way. Tried to find a solution on the vue js official documentation page, but the examples given are too basic to get any direction from it.
Thanks.

Comment: How is loadUsers called? what "pagination button"?  and what debugging have you done?  Does loadUsers run? Is the API call successful? What value does `response.data.page_size` have?  Not sure what the expected result should be here not knowing how your function runs or what any values are. "it doesn't work" isn't a good technical description of a problem. Explain the _behavior_, actual vs. expected results, values, etc.

Comment: It looks like you want to do server-side pagination. Vuetify has a dedicated component for this, [v-data-table-server](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/server-side-tables/#server-side-paginate-and-sort)

Comment: @yoduh not sure what other information you want.  loadUsers is called within the script as you can see right under the function's declaration.The function returns the response successfully and page_size is an integer (10).  The function is called only at first render, because the reactive page variable's value is not changed by the pagination component. My question does not only say things "don't work", not sure where you have that from. Let me repeat it: the pagination component not updating the page reactive variable and because of that the table not getting rerendered.

Comment: @MoritzRingler, that's what I used initially, but it doesn't seem to be taking custom css classes. Struggling to do any styling on it, plus vuetify does not recommend it to be used in production.

Comment: First to address your criticisms of my questioning: you did say "Surprisingly it doesn't work" and when clicking pagination button that "nothing happens", which strictly speaking isn't true.  I was digging for the info such as whether the function runs, if the API call was successful, if values were being assigned, etc.  It also wasn't clear to me when loadUsers runs because it's in a 1 line code block by itself, which means it could exist in a function not shown. I think maybe it was supposed to be included in the block above it which would've made it more clear.

Comment: I understand now that you believe your function should rerun when the component rerenders, but that's not true in Vue.  I will post an answer offering a solution

Comment: @yoduh There was no criticism in my response. Wasn't sure how else to make my question more understandable, and I responded from my phone where didn't notice that the function call is in a different code block. Btw the "Surprisingly it doesn't work" meant to be sarcastic, because I find vuetify really poorly documented, but that's maybe just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a component rerenders, it only reruns code that is executed in the `<template>` of the component.  Script code and the functions within it don't automatically rerun. There are two ways to have your `loadUsers` function rerun when `page` updates.

#### 1. Using `update:model-value` event

This is the event that [v-model](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) uses to update it's binded variable.  You can use this same event to run some code whenever the v-model updates.

```html
<v-pagination
  v-model="page"
  @update:model-value="loadUsers"
  :length="pageNumbers"
></v-pagination>
```

#### 2. Using a watcher

[watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) are used to run code in response to some change in state.  You can use this to "watch" the `page` value, and run some code any time it updates.

```js
watch(page, () => {
  loadUsers()
})
```

One other thing is that I would remove the `page` parameter from the loadUsers definition as it's unnecessary.  You can just reference the `ref` itself with `page.value`.

```js
const loadUsers = async () => {
  await HTTPClient.getData('/user-manager/users?page=' + page.value)
  ...
}
```

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNp9UMtqwzAQ/JVFFzvgB20KheCE9h9CL3UPQl7bAlkSejgtIf9ePQjxpb3oMTs7M7ufV2INa9+1blaP5EA6h4sW1OGplwDdwFdgglp77InDb1czlA5NT1I5ENZa04lL6riSGQJY60UNKEJLqGFP7vhBoJzcHPCXB2iUlwMOAWTcMLGhv3k9hCCHJFavVHgMrEGdZzzPXE535qlrtyly8DYkD6+u3cwTvpYZrh1YdF4nIl+0Mg6uYHCs4EIdm+EGo1ELFGEjReQwJa2DOAscI6982kUxgNFLFi3hEarcwTXHil1KYCPUVBZu5haMlxZwRfMDeTRQY5ItqnQ1acagDXDLBilPGWsVSLx8UAHH098GVFj1r0vWyA7h7Nq8j7AJcqvIvtk3ryTfz3vy9Qv+DLIR)

Comment: Thank you master, really appreciate your help. The @update attribute did the trick. To be honest, I thought that whatever is declared with the ref function becomes like a state variable in react, and then every change on it will be picked up by vue. As mentioned before, I'm thinking too much in a reactish way, need more practice with vue. Thanks for the help again, and sorry for being annoying.